# Find similarities with datastore

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Let's say a user can input multiple strings, server processes it and stores it inside datastore. Is it possible query on the number of similarities (without any work around)? Or is there a beter solution to this?

**Example Query:** get id where value similair to "a, b, c"

Returns: 1, 8, 9, 6, 10, etc..

**Example data:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix your data structure so you have one row per id and value.  String manipulation functions are not particularly good in SQL.

With you data, you can do this:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when ',' || value || ',' like '%,a,%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when ',' || value || ',' like '%,b,%' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when ',' || value || ',' like '%,c,%' then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as nummatches
from t
order by nummatches desc;
```

The concatenation operator varies among databases; it might be `+`, `&`, or `concat()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SQL like queries on the datastore. The datastore uses efficient, but quite limiting indexing.

However, you can have repeated entries in a single index for the same object.

So one way to do this, if you have a limited set like (a,b,c,d), is to 
store all combinations in sorted order:

```
object 1: tags = ["a", "b", "c", "ab", "bc", "abc"]
object 2: tags = ["a", "c", "d", "ac", "cd", "acd"]
```

You can also do searches for prefixes, i.e. the first N letters of an indexed string.

Another alternative is to query for all objects that contain "a", then all that contains "b" etc, and do the intersection in software. In your example that would be rather inefficient. It can be efficient if you only have a few occurrences of the same value and request keys only, then do the intersection before you request the actual objects from the datastore.

Designing models for the Datastore that supports efficient queries can be challenging and requires quite a bit of planning. You might consider using the CloudSQL solution if you only work with small datasets.